# how to get the arraylist from the hashmap in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;
//import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class teste{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

I just want the final `arraylist` for each key for display purpose which is :

The returning values of the key :`[silicone baby dolls for sale, ego ce4, venus, sample,blue]`

The returning values of the key :`[apple, banana, key, kill]`

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? Do you get an error message? Whats the output?

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `addToList` (especially the code that generates the output)?

Comment: The full program is there for your reference. I have posted the whole program along with the CSV file and the output and as well as the expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for separate Lists for `Keyword` and `Alternate`.

What you need is `Map` which has as key the `Keyword` from your csv data and as value a `List` which holds all the `Alternate` values corresponding to a `Keyword`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> alternateMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Note that putting a value into a map with a key which is already present in that map will overwrite the previous value. So you have to put the list only the first time you find a new `Keyword`, i.e. when trying to add an alternative for a keyword, first check whether the corresponding List exists in the map, if not then create a List and put into the map, then add the `Alternate` to that list.

```
while(...) {
    String keyword = ...;
    String alternate = ...;
    // check whether the list for keyword is present
    List<String> alternateList = alternateMap.get(keyword);
    if(alternateList == null) {
        alternateList = new ArrayList<>();
        alternateMap.put(keyword, alternateList);
    }
    alternateList.add(alternate);
}

// printing the result
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> alternateEntry : alternateMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(alternateEntry.getKey() + ": " + 
           alternateEntry.getValue().toString());
}
```

**EDIT**

After running your code it seems to working fine. The List is returned by `entry.getValue()`. Just add this to the end of your main method:

```
for(Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : example.items.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " +  entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

and it should give you the output you want

```
ego kit: [silicone baby dolls for sale, ego ce4, venus, sample, blue]
samsung: [apple, banana, key, kill]
```

Note: the code above was not compiled but should give you a hint how to map your data.

Comment: a guava multimap is a bit more elegant, though not standard.

Answer (score 3):

```
HashMap hm=new HashMap();

ArrayList ln=new ArrayList();

  ln.add("hi");

  ln.add("heloo");

  ln.add(123);

 hm.put("somename", ln);

 ArrayList ls=(ArrayList)hm.get("somename");
```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<String> values= new ArrayList<>(hashmap.values());`

`String` could be any other object type